# Arduino.SE is now a full site. Should we add a migration path to it?

Tags: feature-request, migration, arduino

Arduino.SE is now a [full site](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/congratulations-arduino-se-is-graduating) after graduating out of beta. This means that it's already eligible for migration paths across the SE network.

**Should we add a migration path to it?**

IMHO it makes perfect sense to do so, as there are currently a lot of manual migrations (done by the moderation team) from EE.SE to Arduino.SE, and the `arduino` tag is the most frequent one here.

Comment: So.. I think this is a great question, but I don't agree that it makes sense. Should I upvote or downvote? :)

Comment: @pipe  On this meta, upvotes or downvotes of questions and answers show agreement or disagreement.

Comment: The migration would certainly help. However, most of the questions on the Arduino SE are either programming questions or external shields for the Arduino. Any questions about the Arduino on the EE SE are hardware related issues like, "Why is my ATMega chip not working?" or "There's something that I don't understand about the specifications."

Comment: You can always leave it up to the moderators to move it, if they get sick of requests, shouldn't they be the first to ask for a feature like this? Having the moderators look at the questions before they are moved gives another check box so bad questions are not moved (and rejected)

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit skeptical. I think the migration path report tool is pretty bad at the moment, I rarely want to move things to Super User. I don't think adding Arduino to the list without adding a few more would add much convenience.

If you take a look at the [migration](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration) tag here on meta you will see that a large percentage is about bad migrations to Arduino. I kinda agree that too many are migrated for no good reason, so an easy path may even be counterproductive.

I would not want Arduino added unless DSP and Physics are added to the (now very small) list. Either that or an easy way to select a place for migration.

Comment: I disagree.  Most of the arguments about migration to A.SE are because of moderator intervention.  Moderators, in fact, need to intervene, because the migration tool sucks.  I'd vote to include the Arduino Migration (and a couple of others from the hit parade; SU, Physics, RPi, Engineering) in a short migration list, and let the community moderate the way the community is supposed to moderate.  The "don't migrate garbage" rule will be upheld because there won't be a reason for mods to migrate before the process is done, and garbage will just be closed.

Comment: In any case, there won't be a need for "why was this migrated" arguments, because the answer will always be "because our community said it should have been".

Answer (score 1):

This question would be incomplete without migration statistics.  The migration statistics report is [broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298079/migration-stats-pages-seem-to-be-broken), unfortunately.  It doesn't show details about origin and destination.  It will be about 90 days until the migration statistics report works properly.

In the meantime, here's statistics from autumn 2016.

> 2016 Oct 18    Statistics for the last 90 days
>
> Arduino.SE total questions: 8,735
>   (from sidebar on the front page)
>
> Arduiuno.SE → EE.SE: 5 posts migrated. 0% rejected.
>
> EE.SE questions tagged [arduino]: 4,543
>   (from counter on sidebar, includes closed, doesn't include deleted)
>
> EE.SE → Arduino.SE: 70 posts migrated. 17% rejected.
>
> StackOverflow questions tagged [arduino]: 9,310

Comment: I can see some in review tools.  Overall, we have less than 2 migrations out per day, and that's to all groups.

Comment: What a time for the tool to go down. Last time I checked the rejection percent was low.