# "belongs on another site on the stackexchange network"

Tags: feature-request

When VTCing a post (VingTC? VTC-ing?), if you pick that it belongs on another SE site, you're given two options, Superuser and meta.EE.SE. But very frequently questions crop up that belong on StackOverflow, or Arduino.SE, or Physics.SE, or DIY.SE, or any number of other SE sites; the ones listed are just the ones I can think of off the top of my head.

I found someone a few months ago asking [a similar question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6780/flag-a-question-choices-for-suggesting-another-site), where it was said that "that's another question". As I was just wondering about this myself, here's that other question: Should we add more options to the "belongs on another site" flag/close reason? And if so, who has the authority to do so?

Comment: More old meta threads on this topic: [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2800/7036), [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5110/poor-migration-options), [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6276/arduino-se-is-now-a-full-site-should-we-add-a-migration-path-to-it).

Comment: I know the Arduino.SE people have complained about bad migrations before: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/another-bad-migration-to-arduino

Comment: The only site which gets a decent amount of good AND off topic here AND on topic question migrations out from here is really DIY.se

Answer (score 2):

The limited amount of sites to pick from is a known problem for all SE sites, not just EE. Ideally all SE sites would have a combo box where you could pick any existing site. But for now we just use the custom close option and type it, like:

> I'm voting to close this as off-topic since pure programming questions belong on https://stackoverflow.com/.

The reason why there's been no development on this feature is likely because migrating posts is kind of frowned upon, network-wide. The person who suggests the migration are often not aware of the policies of the target site, and the question rarely ends up in a better place after migration. Meaning we just end up handing over crap questions to someone else, while at the same time confusing the poster. Therefore it seems that SE is leaning towards getting rid of migration altogether.

So currently the stance, SE network-wide, is rather just to close the question and prompt the poster to manually re-post it on the relevant site *after making sure it is on-topic there*.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option, a diamond mod can move them if they are flagged and brought to the mod's attention. You could do this by using the moderator flag option or in chat. Make sure you have a good reason to move the question and that it should exist on the other site.

Check the sites guidelines for on-topicness before requesting a move. There isn't any sense in moving a question to a site if it isn't on topic there either and that creates needless work for the mod's on both sites.